# How do I power on devices in CCNA Packet Tracer?

Tags: cisco

As the question says, i need an answer. I cannot find the power button.

Comment: Try and check if the switch and router are of the same name and type. Dissimilar networks might not get turned on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you double click on a device in Packet Tracer, there is a section for the physical parts of the device (I believe the far right tab, but I can't be sure I'm not close to my computer with Packet Tracer). Here you can change and add drives, interfaces by drag and drop. On that same page there is also the power switch.

Answer (score 3):

Double Click the device which you want to switch on.Go to physical,Click zoom in,See there is a switch to power on and off.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the device the power button on there, (physically in the picture) is interactive click on the power button as if you would physically turn on and off the router itself.

Answer (score 0):

from the module, drag and drop the AC power supply. and wait for the device to boot. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Physical folder allows for adding new hardware and restarting the device.

1. Select device icon (one click)
2. Select Physical Folder
3. Scroll to the far right for power button
4. Toggle power switch off/on to restart device

There is a **Power Cycle Devices** button at the bottom of main workspace to restart all devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you zoom in, there is a power port (i could not find a power switch on my IP phone). drag the power adapter from the bottom area of the screen, and bring the male end of the power connector to the female port on the phone. You really have to connect the two ends as you would in real life.

Answer (score 0):

Power Cycle Devices

The Power Cycle Devices button on the Realtime Bar allows you to power-cycle all of the devices in your network. Pressing it turns all devices off and then turns them back on. Pressing this button will also clear all events if you are running a simulation with the network. The Power Cycle Devices button is also available in Simulation Mode. See the "Simulation Mode" help section for more information.

If you reset the network, you will lose the current running configuration on all routers and switches. Before you click the Power Cycle Devices button, be sure to issue the copy running-config startup-config Cisco IOS command sequence on all routers and switches to retain the current network configuration after the reset.

to power cycle a switch,  go down to the realtime bar on the far left and click the circle.  When you hover over it, it says "power cycle"

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to open the physical tab when double clicking it was only opening the CLI and my physical tab was hidden but i found the solution on another thread  :

Try select Option from menu bar, click "Preference", switch to "Hide" tab and uncheck the "Hide physical tab" box. Hope this helps.